# Fatal error C1083 while compiling mex file in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, compiler-errors, mex

**mex_example0.cpp**

```
#include "mex.hpp"   
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"   
#include <iostream>    
using namespace matlab::data;   
using matlab::mex::ArgumentList;    
class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {    
public:    
    void operator()(ArgumentList outputs, ArgumentList inputs) {    
        ArrayFactory factory;   
        TypedArray<double> x = std:: move(inputs[0]);   
        for (auto& i: x){   
            i += 5;   
        }    
        outputs[0] = x;    
        std::cout<<"Hello MEX"<<std::endl;     
    }   
};
```

**MATLAB code**

```
mex mex_example0.cpp
```

**Error**

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
Error using mex
mex_example0.cpp
C:\Users\iisermbionap\Downloads\mex_example0.cpp(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
file: 'mex.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I am using MATLAB 2015a and MVC 2012 professional.
Can somebody please help me how to rectify this error.

Comment: have you tried: `#include <mex.h>` ? Its what I use in my cpp files.

Comment: MATLAB 2015a does not support the C++ Data API. That was introduced in 2017 or so. You will need a newer version of MATLAB to run that MEX-file, or you will have to rewrite it to use the C API.

Answer (score 0):

The file "mex.hpp" is part of the [C++-MEX interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/cpp-mex-api.html). This was introduced in R2018a. See this [Release Note](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=MEX&startrelease=R2018a&endrelease=R2018a&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=MEX). In R2015a, you need to use the C-MEX interface. You can write your code using C++, but it must use the `mexFunction` [C-language interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html).